# Testing our own SCORM

Tags: scorm

We have been building a SCORM packager and API, customized for our own applications, so we don't have to use tools like Storyline or Lectora to provide content to an LMS.
Our test package seems to work fine on Scorm Cloud and Moodle. So, we are happy, but not 100% sure we are done.

Our question is therefore: is there another method to test our SCORM capability before sending packages to customers?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Download the SCORM Conformance Test Suite from ADL (e.g. http://www.adlnet.org/resources/adl-conformance-test-suite-verion-1_2_7?type=software_downloads) and test, test, test.

Long answer: If you don't know where you're going, any road'll take you there. I mean, what are you trying to achieve? If you wanted your content to work in SCORM Cloud and Moodle, you're ok. If you wanted it to work in EVERY LMS, it will never happen, because there are dozens of LMS with poorly implemented SCORM API. If you wanted to legally cover your behind, you should look into your service agreement. What does it say about determining "broken content"? What do you do (legally speaking) if your content works everywhere except your client's LMS?

Ideally, you should determine quality criteria in the agreement, make sure you comply with those and define what happens if your content doesn't work for your client.

Answer (score 0):

adding to Sergey's response: all you can do beyond the conformance test suite and SCORM Cloud is test in as many LMSs as possible. They definitely have quirks. At a minimum, I suggest downloading and installing every major open-source LMS you can find, including Ilias and Sakai. You might also be able to get free trials for commercial LMSs if you contact them directly.